# Fill row with color after copy to new sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I was able to do minimum changes to some coding I found off bits here and there. But I am at wits so I hope I can received some help with this line of VBA code please :

```
With Worksheets(3)                       
    Worksheets(1).Range(Worksheets(1).Cells(intCopyRow, 1), _
        Worksheets(1).Cells(intCopyRow, bytColumnsInData)).Copy _
    Destination:=.Cells(.Cells.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
End With
```

I hope to add color to the row after I copy the mismatch row to the new sheet3. How should I go about changing this code to do the adding of color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line perhaps?

```
' colors the row Red
.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).EntireRow.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
```

Comment: It works great..i can see there is a bit laggy with color filling the entire Row. Can i shorten the coloring the row length to maybe 20 column?
Do i use 

Offset(1, 0)  instead of EntireRow to control the length of the row?

Comment: @saina No, If you need to color only one cell, then remove `EntireRow`. e.g `.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) `. If you need specific size of Column, then use `Resize` e.g. Coloring 20 columns `.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Resize(, 20).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)`